# Insert based on select of hstore column

Tags: postgresql, hstore

In try to insert value from a hstore (postgreql) to a more generic table

In my car table, I have theses fields

```
id
fields (hstore)
```

My store table, I have theses fields

```
id
key
value
car_id
date
```

How to loop to my fields property in insert key, value to my store table.

Is there a way to do it with a select command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example data:

```
insert into car values
(1, 'brand=>ford, color=>yellow'),
(2, 'brand=>volvo, mileage=>50000, year=>2015');
```

Use the function [`each(hstore)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#idm46046812421968) to get pairs `(key, value)` of hstore column:

```
select id, key, value
from car, each(fields);

 id |   key   | value  
----+---------+--------
  1 | brand   | ford
  1 | color   | yellow
  2 | year    | 2015
  2 | brand   | volvo
  2 | mileage | 50000
(5 rows)
```

The insert command may look like this:

```
insert into store (car_id, key, value)
select id, key, value
from car, each(fields);
```